# How to make freebsd box accessible from internet?

Tags: ssh, freebsd, internet

I have a freebsd box sitting at home. I want my friends to be able to access that via `ssh`. Basically I want to make it some sort of server where they can have an account.

How can I do that?

It seems like a lame question but any inputs are appreciated. It can be connected to internet all the time. I believe, I need to host it on some free hosting service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open up and port forward ssh on whatever has your external IP address at your house.  Usually this is some sort of small router.  Although, at my house thats another FreeBSD box, which is probably the real way to go.  Make the BSD box your router, NAT on it etc.  Once you have that ready they will need a server name to use.  If your home IP changes you should probably research a service like dyndns to update a hostname with your new IP when it changes(using a script, usually on the BSD box).  You'd need to post more details about your home network to get more details about how to port forward.

Comment: Thanks much for response. Yes, you guessed it right. I have a modem, a wireless router. This bsd box connects to the router via an Ethernet cable. I have comcast internet connection at home. How do I know if my IP is changing all the time?

Comment: From this: http://getsatisfaction.com/comcast/topics/can_i_get_a_static_ip_with_comcast_internet unless you have business class comcast service it will change.  Although the details on when it will change aren't given, I would assume if you have a power outage and your modem loses power it can change IPs.

Answer (score 3):

The short version is to open an ssh port-forward on your router (details vary, but it's typically quite easy to do) to the machine you want to listen to outside requests.

Then give your friends either your public IP (if you have home internet access, this is non-ideal), or use something like opendns.com to make a public domain that will alis to your router.